# Plex update not installing

Tags: macos, updates, automatic-update, software-update, plex

I'm running a macOS Plex server.

I want to update Plex via the "Install Update" button within General settings:

[image: Install Update]

Plex immediately quits, and the spinner says that the update is installing:

[image: The server "Plex" is installing an update]

> The server "Plex" is installing an update
>
> Grab a cup of tea. This may take a couple of minutes.

---

I've had my cup of tea. I've left it spinning overnight. **The Plex process never restarts.**

When I manually open Plex again, it boots up immediately as if nothing happened. **The update was not installed.**

[image: Download Updates]

It alerts me again to "Download Updates" and "Install Update" — but the update never works.

---

The automatic update feature is hitting this same problem, and thus **regularly quits my Plex server and never restarts it**.

Very annoying to try to watch media only to find that the Plex server is not running.

In **my** case the bad update is `Version 1.18.1.2019`, but this seems to be a recurring issue for multiple other versions as well.

---

#### Why is the Plex update not installing?

This seems to be a common issue, discussed often on the Plex forums:
https://forums.plex.tv/t/plex-no-longer-installing-updates/428688/

Plex forum topics are shut down after 90 days of inactivity, and I cannot find any actual solution or explanations for this Plex Updater failure.

Logs are available, but I'm not sure what I should be looking for.

I am mainly looking for Answers that suggest solutions to get the auto-updater working, rather than me manually downloading and installing the update from the Plex website.

Comment: Have you tried manually downloading and installing the update? https://www.plex.tv/en-gb/media-server-downloads/

Comment: Have you looked for log files?

Comment: @Mokubai Manually updating would probably work, but I'd prefer an Answer here on SuperUser that solves the actual in-app-update / auto-update issue.

Comment: @DavidPostill I've looked at the log files but do not see anything obviously wrong. The Plex server shuts down, and the logs stop. Does the updater log its actions?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (and was stuck on the same version as pictured above).

I manually downloaded the latest update (from the link below) and attempted to install it. I kept getting a "Fatal error".

https://www.plex.tv/en-gb/media-server-downloads/

I rebooted and ran the manual installation again. It worked.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation that a manual reinstall works. For other answers on this Question I'm mainly looking for solutions to fix the root cause of the auto-update failure.